# How to see all chrome user profiles when on new computer

Tags: google-chrome, profile

I sign in to Chrome browser on Windows 10 using my Google account.
In the Chrome browser I have 5 profiles all with different gmail account.

Since I sign in to the browser itself I though when having a new laptop signing in to Chrome would restore all profiles. I see the extensions are restored and also web password and other things, but the 5 profiles I have to manually set them up one by one, is this the intended procedure?

Comment: Google user profiles are stored within AppData.  Google has documented the exact location of your user profile on their website.

Comment: Can I transfer them to another computer´s Chrome?

Comment: Of course you can it’s just a folder

Comment: So on the new computer, you created 4 additional Chrome profiles, and signed into each with a different Google account, as you did on your older computer ?

Comment: yes, well I created two then asked this Q